# Solve $\frac3x - \frac4y = 1$ and $\frac7x + \frac2y = \frac{11}{12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we solve the following simultaneous equations:

$$\frac3x - \frac4y = 1$$

$$\frac7x + \frac2y = \frac{11}{12}$$

Comment: We can proceed directly. Or else let $s=1/x$ and $t=1/y$. Then we are solving the system of linear equations $3s-4t=1$, $7s+2t=\frac{11}{12}$. You can probably handle a system of $2$ linear equations in $2$ unknowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{3}{x}-\frac{4}{y}=1$ ---(1)

$\frac{7}{x}+\frac{2}{y}=\frac{11}{12}$ ---(2)

2(2): $\frac{14}{x}+\frac{4}{y}=\frac{11}{6}$ ---(3)

(1)+(3): $\frac{17}{x}=\frac{17}{6}$

Hence $x=6$, and $y=-8$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\frac{1}{x}$ as $w$ and $\frac{1}{y}$ as $v$ . Now you will get two linear equations . Solve the two equations for $w$ and $v$ and the subsequently put $w=1/x$ and $v=1/y$ .

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Solve one for one of the variables, substitute back into the second and solve for other variable.

From the first equation, we have:

$$x = \dfrac{3y}{y+4}$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve two equations like this is to add a multiple of one to the other.  For example, Take $2$ times the second equation and add it to the first.  Explicitly,
$$(\frac{3}{x}-\frac{4}{y})+2(\frac{7}{x}+\frac{2}{y})=1+2\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)  $$

This gives us that,
$$\frac{17}{x}=\frac{17}{6} $$

Multiply both sides, by $x$ and then 6 to get,

$$(6)(17)=17x $$
so,
$$x=6 $$

Once we have what $x$ is equal to we can plug that back into one of our equations.  Let's do that with the first equation.

$$ \frac{1}{2}-\frac{4}{y}=1$$

Solving this gets us that $y=-8$.  You can check your answer by making sure this $x,y$ pair satisfy both equations at once.  Hope that helps!